# Detecting communities results in isolated nodes

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to gather some communities form my graph. However, the resulting communities consist of isolated nodes, which contradicts my understanding of communities.
Here is my essential R/igraph-code:

```
g<-simplify(g)
print("isolates: ")
length(which(degree(g)==0)-1) # says 0

c<-fastgreedy.community(g)

cmem<-community.to.membership(g,c$merges,3081)
w<-which(cmem$membership==0)  
sub<-subgraph(g,w)

print("isolates in subgraph: ")
length(which(degree(sub)==0)-1) # says > 0
```

Did I make a mistake? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to subtract 1 from `which(cmem$membership == 0)`, which is required because igraph indexes the nodes from zero, while R uses a 1-based indexing. Try it again with `w <- which(cmem$membership == 0) - 1` and see if the isolates persist.